# chartjs: need color bars near yAxis scale

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to achieve something like the below image.
[Chart with color band in yAxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbhnn.png)

I already have working version of line chart in different places in our application. In One place we need a chart with color band in yAxis. Somehow I achieved this result [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chartjs-stacked?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstacked-line-chart%2Fstacked-line-chart.component.ts)

But the problems are

1. Not able to adjust the width of the bar
2. Not able to move the position of the bar close to yAxis

Answer (score 0):

You can draw individual boxes directly on the canvas using the [Plugin Core API.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) The API offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code.

First, you would define the color bars in an array as follows:

```
const colorBars = [
  { y: 20, color: "#aad700" },
  { y: 40, color: "#ffe100" },
  { y: 60, color: "#ef0000" },
  { y: 80, color: "#aad700" },
  { y: 100, color: "#ffe100" }
];
```

Then you can define a plugin with the `beforeDraw` hook as shown below:

```
const plugins = [
  {
    beforeDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales["x-axis-0"];
      var yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
      ctx.save();
      var prevY = 0;
      colorBars.forEach((c, i) => {
        ctx.fillStyle = c.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        var yBottom = yAxis.getPixelForValue(prevY);
        var yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(c.y);
        ctx.fillRect(xAxis.left - 10, yTop, 10, yBottom - yTop);
        ctx.stroke();
        prevY = c.y;
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
];
```

> The drawback of this solution is, that you won't see a tooltip when the mouse pointer hovers over the bars.

Please have a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chartjs-stacked-sa1tc4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstacked-line-chart%2Fstacked-line-chart.component.ts) and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a separate x-axis for the bar and name it `"bar-x-axis"` for example. The important thing is to define `offset: false`, `ticks.display: false` and `gridLines.display: false`.

```
xAxes: [{
    stacked: true
  },
  {
    id: "bar-x-axis",
    offset: false,
    stacked: true,
    ticks: {
      display: false
    },
    gridLines: {
      display: false
    }
  }
]
```

Your bar datasets are linked to this new x-axis through the option `xAxisID: "bar-x-axis"` . To change the width of the bars, you would define a value between below 1 for [`barPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration).

```
{
  label: "Low-Moderate",
  backgroundColor: "#ffe100",
  yAxisID: "bar-y-axis",
  xAxisID: "bar-x-axis",
  data: [20],
  barPercentage: 0.5
}
```

Please have a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chartjs-stacked-aokkw6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstacked-line-chart%2Fstacked-line-chart.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for me. in your code you used `beforeDraw`, that cause the gridlines to appear above the the bands. So I used afterDraw. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your problem.